# How to stop docker-compose after process termination

Tags: docker, docker-compose, exit, exit-code, terminate

By default `docker-compose up` keeps running even if some of the containers terminate and `restart` is set to `no`.

Is there a configuration to tell it to terminate (and stop all containers) when one of my containers finishes (the process in CMD terminates)?

Bonus points if it gets the exit code from the process of that container

Comment: @spender Thanks, it does, even if the title wouldn't suggest so directly. I'll vote to close this as a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to supply the

```
--abort-on-container-exit
```

command line parameter to `docker-compose`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

To get an exit code:

```
--exit-code-from SERVICE
```

will return the exit code of `SERVICE`, and implies `--abort-on-container-exit`